# what is the name of the spring boot starter parent pom? org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: spring-boot, maven, artifactory

I'm having a maven install issue, where the error is as follows:

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.4.RELEASE and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 16, column 10 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.4.RELEASE
```

Here is the entry in pom.xml for the parent pom:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

I checked with the dev ops engineer, and he said to check Artifactory to see what version of the spring boot starter parent is there and to use that.

My question is, where/how do I find it within Artifactory? I'm looking under "artifacts", but they are organized by name, not domain, so I need to know what name to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue when I switched from repositories on the internet to an Artifactory repository. The reasons behind my problem were as follows

1. "Artifactory Requests Can Retrieve Artifacts" configuration was disabled inside advanced section of virtual repository
2. Artifactory virtual repository was linked with only local repository. So, Artifactory was searching only in local repo. Never tried remote repositories on internet. So, I created a remote repository in Artifactory and linked it with a virtual repository

After addressing the two points above, my build was successful.

[image: How to enable "Artefactory Requests Can Retrieve Artifacts"]

[image: How to link remote repository to virtual repository]